# wordpress showing extra menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have created a custom theme with 6 menus

```
    // Load Menu
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
    'home_menu' => 'Home Menu',
    'header_menu' => 'header Menu',
    'brand_design' => 'Brand Design Menu', 'container' => false,
    'cycling_design' => 'Cycling Design Menu', 'container' => false,
    'wine_lable_design' => 'Wine Label Design Menu', 'container' => false,
    'fun_projects' => 'Fun PLay Projects Menu', 'container' => false
    ));
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

but as you can see by the picture it adding an extra one see screen cap does anyone have any suggestions!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'container' item in your array is recognized as a menu location. Remove these items to get the intended result.

```
// Load Menu
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
    'home_menu' => 'Home Menu',
    'header_menu' => 'header Menu',
    'brand_design' => 'Brand Design Menu'
    'cycling_design' => 'Cycling Design Menu'
    'wine_lable_design' => 'Wine Label Design Menu'
    'fun_projects' => 'Fun PLay Projects Menu'
    ));
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Comment: Oh. She has a menu with the slug, "container" and it's title is set to `false`.

Comment: this worked but the documents say you can do that so i am not sure what the correct way is to remove the container

Answer (score 0):

There must be another menu registered elsewhere. Do a `var_dump` of `get_registered_nav_menus` to see all your menus. Then find out where that extra nameless one is defined.

```
var_dump(get_registered_nav_menus());
```

Comment: where do i add this var dump to see the output

Comment: You can add it anywhere that gets run on the page. Maybe a page template? Anyway, the other answer is correct. You need to take those "containers" out of your array.

Comment: @Terry Sorry, wrong function call before, see the edit. When you run it, you'll see that you have an extra menu defined with the slug 'container'.

Comment: array(7) { ["home_menu"]=> string(9) "Home Menu" ["header_menu"]=> string(11) "header Menu" ["brand_design"]=> string(17) "Brand Design Menu" ["container"]=> bool(false) ["cycling_design"]=> string(19) "Cycling Design Menu" ["wine_lable_design"]=> string(22) "Wine Label Design Menu" ["fun_projects"]=> string(22) "Fun Play Projects Menu" }

Comment: @Terry, you see this:  `["container"]=> bool(false)` is your problem. Use the code in this answer to fix your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14969154/1270996